# Group Theory Normal Subgroups

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group of order $8$ with $x\in G$ such that $o(x)=4$.

Prove that $x^2\in Z(G)$, where $$Z(G)=\{ x \in G \mid xg=gx\text{ for all }g\in G\}.$$

Comment: I am curious why you chose this title for the question, as it does not mention the word homomorphism at all.

Comment: Sorry, I was engrossed with Homomorphism problems at college.Look I  have changed the title now!

Comment: The question also does not mention any quotient groups.

Comment: it requires the concept of [G:H]..better name this question as normal subgroups

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**HINT:** Any subgroup of index $2$ is normal in $G$.

Comment: Yeah I know, and Z(G) is a normal subgroup!

Comment: That is true as well, but it doesn't help you in this case. Rather, what can $gx^2g^{-1}$ be in $\langle x\rangle$?

Comment: x^2 in <x> is the only option!

Comment: Excellent! So what does that say? $gx^2g^{-1}=x^2$, hence $gx^2=x^2g$, that is, ...

Comment: Yeah, so the order of Z(G) is not all required to be found out?

Comment: No, we don't need the order of $Z(G)$, just that $x^2\in Z(G)$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: An order $2$ subgroup $H$ of any group $G$ is normal if and only if $H \subset Z(G)$.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach by hints:

** For *any* group $\,G\,$ , the quotient $\,G/Z(G)\,$ cannot cyclic non-trivial ;

** Any finite $\,p-$group, $\;p\;$ a prime, has a non-trivial center;

** If $\;G\;$ is a non-abelian group of order $\;2^3=8\;$ , then its center *must* have order two ;

** If the exponent of a quotient group $\,G/N\;$ is $\,m\,$ , then for any $\,g\in G\,$ we get that $\,g^m\in N\,$

Comment: Thanks, I was too much into non-abelian groups. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

If $\langle x\rangle\bigcap Z(G)=1$, then $G\cong\langle x\rangle\times Z(G)$, and hence $G$ is abelian. So we assume $G$ is not abelian. Then $|\langle x\rangle\bigcap Z(G)|\geqslant2$ and $\langle x^2\rangle\leq Z(G)$.